# Like Box plugin. I configured "border_color:white" but still appears a blue border

Tags: facebook

I am using the Like Box plugin. I configured "border_color:white" but still appears a blue border. My website is: www.happyfrogdrums.com

Thank you very much.
Ricard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the RGB code #FFFFFF:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FHappyFrogDrumsBarcelona&amp;width=190&amp;height=258&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;border_color=%23FFFFFF&amp;header=false&amp;appId=415430585146155" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:190px; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I use he RGB code #FFFFFF but the border still appears. Thank you. Ricard.